# Authentication Class with 2 tables

Tags: php, laravel

I Have an application on Laravel and 2 tables ( users , members )
what am trying to do is to use auth function class for both tables , i need to be able to call

```
Auth::attempt(['m_username' => $dy_user_name, 'm_password' => $dy_password])
```

for table members while the default table is users

thank you

Comment: The design doesn't look right here.

Comment: what you are describing is the default authentification system of laravel. just define 2 different guard https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the answer largely depends on what your `members` table does. Without any additional information, I will assume that the entries in this table have some sort of relation to an entry in the `users` table. As such, I would recommend that instead of being able to log in as a member directly, that you log in with the `users` table and `User` model, and then define a relation on the `User` model for the `Member` model:

```php
public function member() 
{
    return $this->hadOne(Member::class);
}
```

Once a user is logged in, you can then access the associated member entry with:

```php
$request->user()->member;
```

If the `members` and `users` table are intended to be authenticated separately, then I would recommend renaming the `members` table to make this clear, and make use of multiple [authentication guards](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#adding-custom-guards), like @N69S suggested in a comment to your question.

Comment: it's working by adding a guard('members') function to auth before login